# How do I go about running cable to an off site garage?

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage

So I want to run power to my off site garage about 20 meters from my land. It would need to run down the alleyway from the back of my garden in a straight line to my garage.

It's been cemented over and I don't know what permissions I would need to get to dig it up or where to check for ownership in order to ask permission, it would either be council or shared land from the residents I would imagine though.

Does anyone have any insights to help me here?

Edit: sorry I missed some important points, I'm in the UK, Swindon specifically.

I want to use it to power a workshop, most power at one time will be 2KW and generally for periods of 10 mins tops, other than that it will be LED lights at about 30w. I may consider a dehumidifier though but probably nothing consistent above 400w. So far I have been using a 50m extension lead that's had some slack.

I considered something overhead but I don't know what I would fix it to since the fence posts down the alleyway have gates on the back.

As far as neighbours permission I know I'll need to talk to a lot of them for permission but I get on well with them so I don't think it will be a problem, it's just whether it will be council owned or not.

Comment: Council should have the records of ownership.  Permissions might be difficult, since might be dealing with a few different departments and neighbours together.  Overhead might be another way instead of digging up an alleyway.  Depending on what you want power for, there might be different solutions to running power lines.

Comment: Presumably UK  location from the word choice here? Since rules vary with locale, helpful to be certain, not guessing. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Your plans on what you want power for might be helpful.  Running a workshop hours a day is much different to wanting a light or two.

Comment: Given the government hassles involved, which Britain is famous for, and the low continuous usage and intermittent medium usage, this setup *is just screaming for* solar/battery.

Answer (score 3):

Lacking details yet:

In *most* cases, the simplest way (though it has costs associated, it's also often either the least expensive way or the only way) to provide utility power to an "offsite" building is to have the utility provide a separate metered service to that building.

They (and not you, normally) have the rights of way for getting the power from their system to end users. Rather than being a single end user with a cable run in common space, you'll become two end users (house and garage) with separate utility feeds to separate meters.

If your needs are limited, these days a solar panel/battery system may pay off for certain uses (the monthly fee for the metered service adds up) such as limited lighting and recharging garden tools, but may not be adequate for others (you're charging your electric car at night, in the winter, and have poor sun exposure during the day in winter's short days.)

Comment: I would have to agree that a separate drop from the local utility company sounds like a _much_ easier, cheaper and lower liability option than attempting to run your own overhead cable. Even presuming the OP got permission from all the neighbors to string it up, he's still going to be liable should someone back into somebody's fence and bring the power line down and electrify that person's car before he can get out. I would take a stab that _most_ countries with (enforced) electrical codes would prohibit this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the combination of:

- Other people's land between your two buildings

and

- Low total usage

this sounds ideal for a solar + battery setup.

Normally I wouldn't recommend that. But because there are other people's property in between your two buildings, running power between your buildings may be very complicated. If you can get an easement and do it legally and safely, great. That would be a one-time cost and *done*. But if you can't get an easement due to legal issues (may not be allowed by either local laws or utility company rules) or lack of permission from the neighbors, a separate utility connection may cost a lot, both in up-front costs and monthly costs.

Since your largest planned usage is 2 kW *for 10 minutes at a time*, solar can be a very practical solution. Let's say you have 50W x 24 hours (though I suspect you won't need the LED lights running all the time) = 1,200 Wh. Add 2 kWh (2 kW run for 10 minutes 6 times a day) and that's a total of 3,200 Wh. Then round things up quite a bit, because large batteries used half-way last a lot longer than small batteries pushed to the limit, and to allow for occasional higher usage - and go for 5 kWh of battery. Plus enough solar to charge up 5 kWh in an average day. Well, more than that because you want it to work in the winter.

How much will all that cost? I don't know! A quick search shows that this will likely end up in the $5,000 - $10,000 range. But if you size things right and do a lot of work yourself (instead of relying on packaged solutions) then I suspect it will be towards the lower end. Still a lot of money, but I think an option worth considering. Big bonus: after installation *no electric bill*.